# Hasura installation problem using docker - PostgreSQL not responding

Tags: postgresql, docker, hasura, hasura-docker

I want to install Hasura using docker. According to the Hasura doc, I created the `docker-compose.yml` file. then I compose docker with `docker-compose up`. In my terminal log, a message comes `LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections`. But when I go to the `http://localhost:8080/`, I find nothing.

I don't understand where is the problem and how to solve it?

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.0.10
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      ## postgres database to store Hasura metadata
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
      ## this env var can be used to add the above postgres database to Hasura as a data source. this can be removed/updated based on your needs
      PG_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
      ## enable the console served by server
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      ## enable debugging mode. It is recommended to disable this in production
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      ## uncomment next line to set an admin secret
      # HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: myadminsecretkey
      
volumes:
  db_data:
```

my terminal:

```
sumon@error-inside hasura % docker-compose up
hasura_postgres_1 is up-to-date
9675a01ed8fd_hasura_graphql-engine_1 is up-to-date
Attaching to hasura_postgres_1, 9675a01ed8fd_hasura_graphql-engine_1
9675a01ed8fd_hasura_graphql-engine_1 | qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
9675a01ed8fd_hasura_graphql-engine_1 | qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
9675a01ed8fd_hasura_graphql-engine_1 | qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
9675a01ed8fd_hasura_graphql-engine_1 | qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
postgres_1        | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres_1        | This user must also own the server process.
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres_1        | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres_1        | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres_1        | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres_1        | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres_1        | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres_1        | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres_1        | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres_1        | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres_1        | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres_1        | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres_1        | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres_1        | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres_1        | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres_1        | waiting for server to start....2021-10-23 04:46:45.991 UTC [50] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.8 (Debian 12.8-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:45.993 UTC [50] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.023 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-10-23 04:46:44 UTC
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.039 UTC [50] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1        |  done
postgres_1        | server started
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | waiting for server to shut down...2021-10-23 04:46:46.242 UTC [50] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres_1        | .2021-10-23 04:46:46.243 UTC [50] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.245 UTC [50] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 57) exited with exit code 1
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.245 UTC [52] LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.279 UTC [50] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_1        |  done
postgres_1        | server stopped
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.358 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.8 (Debian 12.8-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.359 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.359 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.363 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.395 UTC [69] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-10-23 04:46:46 UTC
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:46:46.413 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:51:52.553 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:51:52.555 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:51:52.556 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 75) exited with exit code 1
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:51:52.559 UTC [70] LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:51:52.596 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:52:02.912 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.8 (Debian 12.8-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:52:02.913 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:52:02.913 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:52:02.917 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:52:02.949 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-10-23 04:51:52 UTC
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 04:52:02.967 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:34.960 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.8 (Debian 12.8-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:34.960 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:34.960 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:34.964 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:34.996 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-10-23 04:57:03 UTC
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:36.329 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:36.342 UTC [28] LOG:  redo starts at 0/164DF58
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:36.342 UTC [28] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/164E058: wanted 24, got 0
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:36.342 UTC [28] LOG:  redo done at 0/164E020
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:09:36.367 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1        | 
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:07.556 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.8 (Debian 12.8-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:07.556 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:07.556 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:07.560 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:07.591 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-10-23 05:09:36 UTC
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:08.941 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:08.944 UTC [28] LOG:  redo starts at 0/164E0D0
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:08.944 UTC [28] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/164E108: wanted 24, got 0
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:08.944 UTC [28] LOG:  redo done at 0/164E0D0
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 05:14:08.963 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1        | 2021-10-23 06:21:46.578 UTC [32] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Operation not permitted
```

Comment: It seems that something wrong with volume `- ./db_data:`. Can you remove volume and start with empty database? What's in `docker logs [your hasura container]` ?

Comment: @AlexYu nothing is changing when I remove volume. Volume is created on my docker desktop.

Comment: Question: are you on Linux or MacOS? `qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped` - looks disturbing

Comment: @AlexYu I am on macOS.

Comment: Maybe you're on M1? Does this looks similar to your case https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/6511 ?

Comment: if the existing data is not needed you can try `docker-compose down -v` followed by `docker-compose up`